# Arbitrary ordering of tuple nested in a list in Python

Tags: python, sorting, solr, faceted-search

I have a list of tuples like the following that I'm getting back from Solr:

```
 [('Second Circuit', 34), ('Ninth Circuit', 24), ('Third Circuit', 4), ('Eleventh Circuit', 2)]
```

Note that not only the second, third, ninth and eleventh circuits were returned.

I need to order this according to an ordering tuple I have that looks like this:

```
COURT_ORDER = (
    'Supreme Court',
    'First Circuit',
    'Second Circuit',
    'Third Circuit',
    'Fourth Circuit',
    ...and so on...,
)
```

The desired output, after sorting would be:

```
 [('Second Circuit', 34), ('Third Circuit', 4), ('Ninth Circuit', 24), ('Eleventh Circuit', 2)]
```

Is there a clever way of doing this?

(This needs to get tagged with the Sunburnt tag, if possible, but I can't create it, for lack of points.)

Comment: re the tagging: I hardly see how the source of your data is relevant to the problem of sorting it.

Comment: Sorting facets is something that others that use the Sunburnt library will probably want to do, so it should be tagged appropriately, though I understand that this is primarily a Python question.

Answer (score 4):

Build a dictionary that maps the court name to the desired ranking.  Then sort with a [key function](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-key-function) that looks up the court name to find the ranking:

```
>>> COURT_ORDER = (
    'Supreme Court',
    'First Circuit',
    'Second Circuit',
    'Third Circuit',
    'Fourth Circuit',
    'Ninth Circuit',
    'Eleventh Circuit',
)
>>> court_seq = dict(zip(COURT_ORDER, range(len(COURT_ORDER))))
>>> lot = [('Second Circuit', 34), ('Ninth Circuit', 24), ('Third Circuit', 4), ('Eleventh Circuit', 2)]
>>> sorted(lot, key=lambda t: court_seq[t[0]])
[('Second Circuit', 34), ('Third Circuit', 4), ('Ninth Circuit', 24), ('Eleventh Circuit', 2)]
```

For more insights on how to sort, see the [Sorting HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/howto/sorting.html).

Comment: Karl Mnechtels example using an index into the ordered list means that the dictionary is no longer needed.

Comment: @Paddy3118 A dictionary is preferred for its O(1) lookup time.  Indexing a list is slow and is rarely TheRightWayToDoIt(tm).

Answer (score 2):

`key` the items according to the `index` of the first appearance of their `[0]` item in the `COURT_ORDER`:

```
data = [('Second Circuit', 34), ('Ninth Circuit', 24), ('Third Circuit', 4), ('Eleventh Circuit', 2)]
sorted(data, key = lambda x: COURT_ORDER.index(x[0]))
```